# Microsoft Graph Schema Registration

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I am working on creating a simple calendar app to track the user's Outlook.com calendar. In order to add some custom information I am needing to use Schema Extension as this information must be filterable and to my knowledge there is no filterable on Open Extension data.

I have followed the RegisterSchemaExtension() from the following sample: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/uwp-csharp-snippets-rest-sample/blob/master/O365-UWP-Unified-API-Snippets/Extensions/ExtensionSnippets.cs

and have added the proper scope to my application. I have also added the Directory.AccessAsUser.All permission to my app through the app registration portal at: https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/portal/register-app

Despite this, I am unable to register the schema and get error saying: MethodNotAllowed. I am not sure where to go from here as I haven't been able to find useful resources on the web. Apologies for the English! It is not perfect yet but I am learning!

Comment: Sorry you had issues.  Can you share the error that came back, including the request id and timestamp please?  We'd like to understand what went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

With how complicated the Schema Extension turned out I decided to use Open Extension and do filtering manually.